# How to change view inside ViewPagers Page

Tags: android, layout, android-viewpager

This is from my **custom PageAdapter:**

```
public Object instantiateItem(View collection, int position) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) collection.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View view = null;
    switch (position) {
    case 0: view = dMngr.GetView(inflater); 
        break;
    case 1: view = mMngr.GetView(inflater); 
        break;
    case 2: view = cMngr.GetView(inflater); 
        break;
    }   
    ((ViewPager) collection).addView(view, 0);
    return view;
}
```

this is **cMngr.GetView** code:

```
public View GetView(LayoutInflater inflater){
    View view = null;
    if (showCamDetail){
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cam_view, null);
        ((Button)view.findViewById(R.id.button1)).setOnClickListener(myhandler2);
    } else {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cams_view, null);  
        ((ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.imageView1)).setOnClickListener(myhandler);
    }
    return view;
}

View.OnClickListener myhandler = new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        showCamDetail = true;
        hPageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
};
View.OnClickListener myhandler2 = new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        showCamDetail = false;
        hPageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
};
```

This code changes `layout` on third page only when I swipe to first page and then back to third. 
I need to make it to change `layout` immediately after I click my `ImageView` or `Button`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the difference between the two view states is not too complex, include them both in the same layout and selectively hide/show parts of it with `View.setVisibility(View.GONE)` and `View.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)` as needed. You can `setTag()` your layout after inflation so it's easier to find it later with `findViewByTag()` and you can apply your visibility changes.

Comment: No, it is going to be different layout. With complex changes both in view and logic.

Comment: Try it. If your get performance issues due to too complex view hierarchy, only then go about optimizing it. Recreating views or editing the view hierarchy is not cheap either. So, likely you need something like a `FrameLayout` as root with the two different layouts as children, to be shown or hidden as needed.

Comment: Hm.. I really don't think this is good idea. Can't I just force ViewPager to reload or something?

Comment: Reload works with `notifyDataSetChanged()` if you also override `getItemPosition(Object)` to return `POSITION_NONE` for the `View` you want to reload. It will destroy your page and then reinstantiate it which is likely even more costly in terms of performance.

Comment: Ok, using notifyDataSetChanged with getitemposition returning position_none did the job. It works like a charm now, thx